# Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation when operated with DataTable

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm trying to extract column's data from a `DataTable` to a `List<string>`. sample code below:

```
List<String> userNames = dataTable.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().
                                Select(dr => dr.Field<string>("UserName"))
                                .ToList();
```

And I'm getting error message from Visual Studio 2015:

> Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically
>   dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or
>   expression tree type.

The DataTable have 3 rows, and all data are in type of `string`.

Have googled for hours and still can't solve it. How can I solve this error?

Update: @IvanStoev noticed me that `dataTable` is a `dynamic` variable, not `DataTable`.

Comment: Are you sure that this line produces the error? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The only way I can duplicate the compile error is if the `dataTable` variable is of type `dynamic`. Is that the case? Why it is not `DataTable`?

Comment: @OfirWinegarte Yes. I'm trying to read a excel file by NPOI library.

Comment: @IvanStoev yes it is `dynamic`, not `DataTable`, I've just checked code and update question, sorry for my mistake.

Comment: Then change it to `DataTable` or use **cast** - `((DataTable)dataTable).Rows....`

Comment: @IvanStoev Problem solved, thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks okay but you can also try below:

```
var userNames = (from x in dataTable.AsEnumerable()
                select x.Field<string>("UserName")).ToList();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Have tried this, and it works. Though the problem is `dataTable` is an `dynamic` variable, thanks you anyway.

Comment: Glad to help you, wondering if you vote up :) Happy programming

Answer (score 0):

You have to use AsEnumerable() on DataTable, and then you will operate on DataRows. You can try this:

```
List<String> userNames = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(dr => dr.Field<string>("UserName")).ToList();
```

Comment: This works. Though the problem is `dataTable` is an `dynamic` variable, thanks you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Though it's been answered earlier, I thought it's worth mentioning that
`dynamic` types evaluated at run time, it's obvious to get this compile time errors when we try to use `.` to access property. 
eg.

```
dynamic temp = new MyClass();
temp.prop1  // compile time error.
```

you have to cast this back to specific type , as follow :

```
((MyClass)temp).prop1  //   works.
```

In your case try casting dataTable back to DataTable as

```
((DataTable)dataTable).Rows....
```